# How to calculate the execution time of a process?

Tags: c#

How much time is a process been taking to be executed. I have created some process below and have to find the execution time of these processes. ?

```
        string path = @"C:\Users\Abbas\Desktop\Processes\p"+a+".txt";
        begin = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
        tw.Close();
        end = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
        MessageBox.Show("Process " + a + " created.");
        a++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Stopwatch` class like this:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
tw.Close();

watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: @SheikhAbbas: please upvote and mark as answer if it resolved your problem.